# Chef - Watch and reset custom remote file changes

Tags: chef-infra

I am using `chef` as devOps tool in my stack. All changes are made by `chef` in my scenarios, not anything or anybody else. Not allowing any user to edit a file can be handled with file permissions, but root user is still allowed to edit kind of that files. For example; environment variables are specific for the environment like `test`,`prod` and those variables are defined in `.bashrc` file. I want to make sure that, this file remains as the version in most recent release.

I am not sure that this is true way or not, but my question is;

Is it possible to make `chef` (maybe `chef-client`) to detect that custom changes (which means not by chef itself, maybe via and editor by a human) on server and reset that changes to most recent version.

I looked for it in the documentation and web but couldn't find something may works. `file` and `remote_file` cookbooks have a feature which is `notifies`, but I think this is detecting changes on deployment and changes by chef itself.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `file`, `cookbook_file` or `template` resources with default action (`:create`), Chef will ALWAYS [overwrite](https://docs.chef.io/resource_cookbook_file.html) file content if it differs from the desired state.

```
:create
  Default. Create a file. If a file already exists (but does not match), an update that file to match.
```

As you mentioned, you can add `notifies` if you want to take any additional action on file change.

The previous version of a file can be found in chef backup directory (`/var/chef/backup/` by default or `Chef::Config["file_backup_path"]`), if you'll need them for some reason.

By default `remote_file` redownloads file based on ETag or If-Modified-Since headers.

If you want to redownload file on a local change you would have to add a [checksum](https://docs.chef.io/resource_remote_file.html) to resource call, store checksum somewhere in node/role/environment and update it with each release.

If files you mentioned are simply configuration files you can think about storing them in databags (or built them based on databags) or just store them as cookbook_file/template in your cookbooks.